# Обрезанный блок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

В верстке нуб. Нужно сделать видимыми и кликабельными все элементы меню. z-index в порядке. Сайт: http://4barter.org/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется ul

```
height: auto;
position: absolute; 
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
```

ul>li

```
display: block;
position: relative;
visibility: visible;
```

Comment: Без 100 грамм не разобратся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В блоке `.out` уберите свойство `overflow: hidden`:

[image: Демонстрация решения]